# Snowflake Connector for Python - Doesn't work in Lambda Function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, snowflake-connector

**UPDATE** - I have gotten past the "unable to find snowflake-connector" issue, but now it appears that when I build the Lambda function, some of the dependencies (that the connector relies on) cannot be resolved, even though I can see them in my virtual environment.

> Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
>
> Build Failed Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies -
> {cffi==1.15.0(wheel), cryptography==3.4.8(wheel)} SAM Build has
> failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1 170 has
> failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1

Any ideas why it would not be able to resolve these two when it can resolve the other modules in my virtual environment?

**Original question** - I am  working in Pycharm and trying to connect to snowflake from lambda. I have installed the snowflake connector in the project's virtual environment. I have other packages that I can access from the same lambda without an issue. When I try to use the this one I get this error, indicating that it cannot find the package.

> {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named
> 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package", "errorType":
> "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}

```
 import snowflake.connector
 import os

 def lambda_handler(event, context):       
        # Gets the version
        ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user='my-user',
            account='my-account',
            password="my-password",
            authenticator='externalbrowser',
            warehouse="my-warehouse",
            database="my-database",
            schema="my-schema"
        )
        cs = ctx.cursor()
        try:
            cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
            one_row = cs.fetchone()
            print(one_row[0])
        finally:
            cs.close()
        ctx.close()
```

I tried adding a python file to the root of the project and tried the same code and it was able to connect without a problem so that tells me the the snowflake connector is installed correctly and that lambda just cannot find that one package.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Does [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python/) help?

Comment: I'm not sure. Isn't that for deployment? I'm getting this error developing on my local machine while using a virtual environment. It definitely gives something to explore though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your requirements.txt file contains the dependencies you want to install

```
snowflake-connector-python
```

Keep rest of the code as is

```
import snowflake.connector
import os

 def lambda_handler(event, context):       
        # Gets the version
        ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user='my-user',
            account='my-account',
            password="my-password",
            authenticator='externalbrowser',
            warehouse="my-warehouse",
            database="my-database",
            schema="my-schema"
        )
        cs = ctx.cursor()
        try:
            cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
            one_row = cs.fetchone()
            print(one_row[0])
        finally:
            cs.close()
        ctx.close()
```